# error on VaultStringCredentialBinding in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, hashicorp-vault

Team,
I am trying to pull token from vault and this class is not being identified. any hint?

it is referred here [VaultStringCredentialBinding](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/hashicorp-vault-plugin/com/datapipe/jenkins/vault/credentials/common/VaultStringCredentialBinding.DescriptorImpl.html)

error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface java.util.List is named VaultStringCredentialBinding
```

jenkinsfile

```
        stage('Publish to artifactory') {
            environment {
                HEAD = sh(script: 'git rev-parse HEAD', returnStdout: true).trim()
            }
            steps {
            container('main') {
                    script {
                        withCredentials([$class: 'VaultStringCredentialBinding', credentialsId: 'TOKEN', variable: 'PASSWORD' ]){
                            env.TOKEN = variable
                    }
                    sh "env | grep TOKEN”

               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: First implication would be that the Vault Credentials plugin is not installed.

Comment: it is installed. as i can use other classes.